# Do I need to use my own company name for an app to show up?

Tags: android

I just uploaded my app and it shows Published o nthe developer console. However, for most other apps, I am referring com.companyname.appname and in this case i made net.randomname.appname, it is not showing even with `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.randomname.appname`
I wonder what I am doing wrong? I know it takes time to show up in the app store. But usually it is supposed to show up with the above link. Any clue how I can fix the same?

Thanks!
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you dont, you just wait a few hours and it will be up there, what's you app link anyways?

Comment: its live in the app store now!

Answer (score 2):

It should show up. But as you said, it takes time. Depending on how busy the play store is, more than a day! So be calm :) It will show up!

Comment: I know it takes time on the app store.However, does it take time to show up when you directly refer it aswell? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.randomname.appname

Comment: Yes usually 2-3 hours

Comment: great thanks, will wait for a while then and find out! thanks